# Problems formulating a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a `CustomerOrderCopy` table in which I want to select the `CustomerName` and `InvoiceDate` from a specific time range. The same result can't be in the other time range specified.

How can I accomplish this?

```
SELECT CustomerName, InvoiceDate
FROM CustomerOrderCopy
WHERE (InvoiceDate BETWEEN '08.09.2016' AND '08.10.2016' ) 
AND (InvoiceDate NOT BETWEEN '08.11.2016' AND '09.06.2016')
```

Comment: AND NOT (InvoiceDate BETWEEN '08.11.2016' AND '09.06.2016') ?

Comment: @JanDoggen I think Ronny wants to exclude the customers who also had an order in the exclude range

Comment: Create an sql fiddle with your table structure and some dummy data.  http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Fastest road to an answer is to show a sample table with some data along with the output you want.

Comment: share sample data with desired output

Answer (score 3):

Try to use NOT EXISTS:

```
 SELECT CustomerName, InvoiceDate 
   FROM CustomerOrderCopy
  WHERE (InvoiceDate BETWEEN '08.09.2016' AND '08.10.2016' ) 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      FROM CustomerOrderCopy as t2
                      WHERE t2.CustomerName=CustomerName 
                        AND (InvoiceDate BETWEEN '08.11.2016' AND '09.06.2016' )
                    );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select C1.CustomerName, C1.InvoiceDate
from CustomerOrderCopy C1
left join CustomerOrderCopy C2
  on C1.CustomerName = C2.CustomerName -- use ID if you have it
  and C2.InvoiceDate between '08.11.2016' AND '09.06.2016'
where C1.InvoiceDate between '08.09.2016' AND '08.10.2016'

and C2.CustomerName is null -- This will exclude all those where there is a match
```